# Need help on looping n rows in table?

Tags: ruby, watir

I need help on iterating the table looping n rows.

Table name: Table= $b.table(:id, /grid/)

```
1   2   3   4   5    
2   100 2000            
3   150 3000    text    dropdown    
4   200 4000            
5   250 5000    text    dropdown    
n   300 6000
```

However, i got the following error message when i used the following code

```
browser.table(:id, /grid/).rows.each do |row|
 row[5].select("Value from the dropdown") if row[4].text.exists?
end
```

Error

```
C:/Watir Scripts/Project/Debit.rb:58:in `block in report': undefined method `exists?' for "Account Number":String (NoMethodError)
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:21:in `each'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:21:in `each'
 from C:/Watir Scripts/Project/Debit.rb:57:in `report'
 from driver.rb:36:in `run'
 from driver.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

So i tried to tweak the script and wrote as below.

```
browser.table(:id, /Grid/).rows.each do |row|
if row[4].text!= ""
  row[5].select("Value from the dropdown") 
end
```

Then i got the following error message.

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/container.rb:36:in `extract_selector': expected Hash or (:how, 'what'), got ["Exclude: Duplicate Account"] (ArgumentError)
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/generated.rb:2163:in `select'
 from C:/Watir Scripts/Project/Credit.rb:53:in `block in report'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:21:in `each'
 from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.2.3/lib/watir-webdriver/element_collection.rb:21:in `each'
 from C:/Watir Scripts/Project/Debit.rb:51:in `report'
 from driver.rb:36:in `run'
 from driver.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

So i think we need to use (how, what) expressions, can you help me how to use those expressions in 'each' command?

Comment: `if row[4].text.exists?` => `if row[4].text.present?`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
row[5].select("Value from the dropdown")
```

to:

```
row[5].select_list.select("Value from the dropdown")
```

To understand what's going on, look at the types you get back

```
row[5]             #=> #<Watir::TableCell>
row[5].select_list #=> #<Watir::Select>
```

(The reason you don't get a `NoMethodError` when calling `TableCell#select`, is because `#select` is an alias for `#select_list` - a side effect of the code generation in watir-webdriver).

Answer (score 1):

could part of the problem here be zero based indexing of the cell's under watir-webdriver?

as a troubleshooting tactic, you might try just using .flash  on the cells to be sure you are looking at the right ones

instead of trying to manipulate the select_list  maybe just

```
row[5].flash unless row[4] == ''
```

or even just change the inner loop to something as simple as

```
row[4].flash
```

to be sure it's looking at the right cells.

If it's looking at the right cells, then maybe try to identify the select_list by index (it should be the only one in the cell)

The other thing is, if there's a header row, and there's text in that row, it could be trying to find a selection list on that row and failing..  so you may need to look for perhaps more specific text than just 'not blank' as it were..  Is there a pattern to the text that appears in the cells you want that would be different from the header row, that would allow you to better match what you are looking for in that 4th column?